# How can I pass a TypeScript color variable to an HTML div?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, sass

How can I pass a TypeScript color variable to an HTML div? I am also using scss

.ts

```
{colorBorder}
```

.scss

```
.colorBorder{
    border: 5px var(--colorBorder);
}
```

.html

```
<div class="colorBorder">
```

Comment: Maybe like this? `document.querySelector('.colorBorder')?.style.setProperty('--colorBorder', 'red')`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn you mean it goes like this?<script>document.querySelector('.colorBorder')?.style.setProperty('--colorBorder', 'red') </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ngStyle`](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/) or set the particular style like `[style.border]` like so.

```
<p [ngStyle]="{ border: '1px solid ' + borderColor }">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

or

```
<p [style.border]="'1px solid ' + borderColor">
    Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwus8m)

Comment: I tried like this but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @ALAINTORRES updated my answer with a working example!